# Not able to receive messages in sequential order from concurrent session in Azure Service Bus

Tags: c#, .net-core, azureservicebus

I am new to Azure Service Bus and trying to understand how session enabled queue works.

I have 3 console applications: 1 Message Sender app, to send message to queue and 2 Message Receiver apps.
The Azure Service Bus queue is session enabled and I am trying to implement concurrent sessions.

Each user who runs the message sender console application will send a message to the queue and this message has to be received by both receiver console applications.
And the receiver applications must receive/process each message in sequential order, Receiver1 first and then Receiver2. For that I am tagging each message
with the receiver application name while sending and then in receiver code checking the tag name for the receiver application to receive.

Below is the code I am using for sending and receiving message.

**Message Sender code:**

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    await SendSessionMessagesAsync();
}

public async Task SendSessionMessagesAsync()
{
    // Below userList coming from db
    foreach (var user in userList)
    {
        List<ReceiverApplicationName> receiverApplicationNameList = new List<ReceiverApplicationName>();
        var receiverApplicationNames = //getting the ReceiverApplicationName list from appsettings.json, [ "Receiver1", "Receiver2" ]
        foreach (var item in receiverApplicationNames)
        {
            ReceiverApplicationName receiverApplicationName = new ReceiverApplicationName();
            receiverApplicationName.UserId = user.Id;
            receiverApplicationName.ApplicationName = item;
            receiverApplicationNameList.Add(receiverApplicationName);
        }
        foreach (var queueMessageItem in receiverApplicationNameList)
        {
            var messageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queueMessageItem);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody));
            message.SessionId = "Session " + queueMessageItem.UserId;
            Console.WriteLine($"Sending message for UserId: {queueMessageItem.UserId}, SessionId: {message.SessionId}, Message: {messageBody}");
            await queueClient.SendAsync(message); // 2 messages(Receiver1 and Receiver2) for each user
        }
    }
}
```

**Message Receiver code(Receiver1):**

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    RegisterOnSessionHandlerAndReceiveSessionMessages();
}

public void RegisterOnSessionHandlerAndReceiveSessionMessages()
{
    var sessionHandlerOptions = new SessionHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
    {
        MaxConcurrentSessions = 2,
        MessageWaitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        AutoComplete = false,
    };
    queueClient.RegisterSessionHandler(ProcessSessionMessagesAsync, sessionHandlerOptions);
}

public Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
{
    _logger.LogError(exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception, "Message handler encountered an exception");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public async Task ProcessSessionMessagesAsync(IMessageSession session, Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReceiverApplicationName>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));
    if (result.ReceiverApplicationName == "Receiver1")
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message for UserId: {result.UserId}, Session: {session.SessionId}, Message: SequenceNumber: {message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber}, Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}, at: {DateTime.Now}");
        await session.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
}
```

**Message Receiver code(Receiver2):**

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public async Task MainAsync()
{
    RegisterOnSessionHandlerAndReceiveSessionMessages();
}

public void RegisterOnSessionHandlerAndReceiveSessionMessages()
{
    var sessionHandlerOptions = new SessionHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler)
    {
        MaxConcurrentSessions = 2,
        MessageWaitTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        AutoComplete = false,
    };
    queueClient.RegisterSessionHandler(ProcessSessionMessagesAsync, sessionHandlerOptions);
}

public Task ExceptionReceivedHandler(ExceptionReceivedEventArgs exceptionReceivedEventArgs)
{
    _logger.LogError(exceptionReceivedEventArgs.Exception, "Message handler encountered an exception");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

public async Task ProcessSessionMessagesAsync(IMessageSession session, Message message, CancellationToken token)
{
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReceiverApplicationName>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));
    if (result.ReceiverApplicationName == "Receiver2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received message for UserId: {result.UserId}, Session: {session.SessionId}, Message: SequenceNumber: {message.SystemProperties.SequenceNumber}, Body:{Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body)}, at: {DateTime.Now}");
        await session.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
    }
}
```

**Results:**
I am not able to receive messages in sequential order within a session id. The timestamp of the received message for Receiver1 and Receiver2 are not in sequence. For ex, in UserId = 2, Receiver1 should receive message before it is received by Receiver2 application. In a session, message should be received in a order in which they were added or I am incorrect.

Message Sender output:
[MessageSender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXlhd.png)

Receiver1 output:
[Receiver1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm9iz.png)

Receiver2 output:
[Receiver2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrKi4.png)

Comment: With multiple receivers running concurrently, you can't expect messages to arrive in any particular order. If your design relies on messages being processed in sequence, you should revisit your design.

Answer (score 1):

Messages from a given session can only be processed by a single consumer. You cannot scale out the processing of a single session. The documentation states it clearly:

> When the session is accepted and held by a client, the client holds an exclusive lock on all messages with that session's session ID in the queue or subscription. It will also hold exclusive locks on all messages with the session ID that will arrive later.

See Service Bus [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) for details.